# NoMethodError: undefined method `exists?' for #<Aws::Resources::Collection:0x00000100b690f8>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, rubygems, aws-sdk

```
unless skip_error_checks
  bucket_source = @@s3.bucket(from_bucket)
  bucket_dest = @@s3.bucket(to_bucket)
  old_object = bucket_source.objects(name)
  new_object = bucket_dest.objects(new_name)
  new_exists = new_object.exists?
  old_exists = old_object.exists?
  if new_exists && old_exists
    return error("#{name} in #{from_bucket} and #{new_name} in #{to_bucket} exist.")
  elsif new_exists && !old_exists
    return error("This action has been done already.")
  elsif !old_exists
    return error("#{name} in #{from_bucket} do not exist it may have been permanently deleted.")
  end
```

i'm using aws-sdk 2.1.4 even though i followed documentation of aws-sdk  seeing nomethod error,Does anyone had same issue

Answer (score 1):

The `exists?` method has been [removed](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby/issues/696) as of version 2.

Some methods [have been added to only some classes](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby/pull/757). If you want to add additional `exists?` the solution is given by the provided link:

> To add additional `#exists?` methods, a waiter must be added to the resource class as `Exists` and that waiter must be defined in the `*.waiters.json` document for that service.

Comment: But in aws-sdk version 2 documentation it has the option   http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/S3/Object.html

Comment: As I said in the answer, it is implemented for some classes only but you can add your own.